# So many Service Bus Transient Errors?

Tags: c#, azure, network-programming, azureservicebus

We have two windows services that live on a Corporate On-Premise Server and that continually send messages to Azure Service Bus in the cloud.  Although the messages do end up on the service bus eventually, there are periods of time where the messages just seem to never make it through for a long stretch of time.

This is causing delay issues for us, as we depend on the message arriving onto the service bus and being processed within a minute.  However, as can be seen below, a message can be 'blocked' for stretches of up to 30-40 minutes before making its way through to Azure Service Bus.  This happens every day, and almost at some time during every hour.

The errors are mainly one of the following (example logs at end of this post):

- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 191.239.XX.XXX:443
- Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection information, then retry.
- No such host is known
- The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:10. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. TrackingId:f2db6377-e17d-401a-b339-11fbb51c7bf7, Timestamp:19/05/2017 12:47:36 AM

The way that we send messages to the service bus is as follows, simplified below:

```
private TopicClient _azureTopic;

...
<Begin Loop>

if (_azureTopic == null)
{
   var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=managerfiddev;SharedAccessKey=AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHHASDFADFAadfadfdfz=EntityPath=mytopic";
   _azureTopic = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
   _azureTopic.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicy.NoRetry;
}

var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message.Message)
{
    MessageId = message.Id.ToString()
};
brokeredMessage.Properties["ReceivedTimestamp"] = DateTime.Now;

_azureTopic.Send(brokeredMessage);

<End Loop>
```

Note:
  There is a deliberate reason why we have a NoRetry policy.  Without wanting to add too much noise to the question, the same message that failed will be tried again in the next iteration (it sends the message to subscribers in a round robin fashion).

### Example log of errors during a small window of time.

> 20:31:51  Event.WindowsService    Event.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1191251
>   Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection
>   information, then retry.
>
> 20:32:00  Event.WindowsService    Event.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1191251
>   No such host is known
>
> 20:32:00  RFID.WindowsService RFID.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1930029
>   No such host is known
>
> 20:32:10  RFID.WindowsService RFID.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1930029
>   No such host is known
>
> 20:32:10  Event.WindowsService    Event.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1191251
>   No such host is known
>
> 20:32:10  RFID.WindowsService RFID.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1930029
>   No such host is known
>
> 20:34:00  RFID.WindowsService RFID.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1930034
>   Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection
>   information, then retry.
>
> 20:38:34  Event.WindowsService    Event.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1191269
>   Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection
>   information, then retry.
>
> 20:38:51  RFID.WindowsService RFID.WindowsService::PublishAzureServiceBusTopicMessage()
>   error trying to synchronise message with Azure. Message ID: 1930043
>   Error during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection
>   information, then retry.

Comment: RetryPolicy is the way to go

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't afford to wait on a retry policy.  If message fails, we need to send the message to a second on-premise subscriber (and then later return to trying again to the first azure subscriber).

Comment: You can configure your client to retry only once and then send it back to the on-premise subscriber. What is the underlying reason not to have a retry policy ?

Comment: We don't want to retry because we can't afford waiting to send the same message to our second subscriber.   So in essence, in the loop it will send to Azure and then send to another WCF service on premise.  If it fails to send to Azure, then it still must go on to sending to the WCF service (without any delay).  We keep a track of what has been sent to azure and wcf seperately, so when the loop goes back to sending to azure, it will retry sending the same message that it had failed on.

Comment: retrypolicy only applies to transient fault so message wont be delivered twice. Also you can configure delay between retries

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  Understand that it won't deliver twice.  Getting it to retry only once, and at 2 seconds later might be worth ago.  Do you happen to know how to set that up (Default policy seems to be exponential and 3 retries?)

Answer (score 0):

Service bus has native retry capabilities on Namespace Manager, Messaging Factory, and Client (see [Retry guidance for specific services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus-retry-guidelines)).

Because it is handling transient exception, you shouldn't have duplicated sent messages.

if you want to retry only once You can configure it like that:

```
var connectionString = "myconnectionstring";
var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
client.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                                        maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                                        maxRetryCount: 1);
```

This should do the trick.

If you want to ensure deduplication, just google azure servicebus deduplication.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I'll try the retry policy.  As long as its very short policy and only tries once more, it may be okay.  Need to verify with the business on this one.  But will likely try this next week and let you know if the matter improves